# Concatenating a string and the size of an array in Assembly x86 MASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I was able to loop through the array and print out the values. However, I also wanted to print out the string "The length of my array is 7", with 7 being the length of (the number of elements) in the array. However, I cannot concatenate the string with the length of the arrays. Please help. Thank you.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 
.data
    myarray byte 23, 2, 3, 40, 5, 16, 7
    x byte 5 
    l dword lengthof myarray 
    msg1 byte "The length of my array is ",0
    msg2 byte "-------------------------------",0
    i byte 0
    .code 
    main PROC 

        mov eax, 0
        mov esi, offset myarray;
        mov ecx, l 



        myloop:
        mov al, [esi]
        call writedec 
        call crlf 
        inc esi 
        mov edx, OFFSET msg1 
        mov edx, l

        loop myloop

        call writestring
        call crlf 
        call crlf

        exit 

        main ENDP
        end main
```

The result I am getting is the following:

```
23
2
3
40
5
16
7

"esimovarray.asm has stopped working"
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. Watch the register values. Use a shorter array temporarily to speed up the debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we only need to change the order of a few lines of code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 
.data
    myarray byte 23, 2, 3, 40, 5, 16, 7
    x byte 5 
    l dword lengthof myarray 
    msg1 byte "The length of my array is ",0
    msg2 byte "-------------------------------",0
    i byte 0
    .code 
    main PROC 

        mov eax, 0
        mov esi, offset myarray;
        mov ecx, l 

        myloop:
        mov al, [esi]
        call writedec 
        call crlf 
        inc esi 
        ;mov edx, OFFSET msg1         ;◄■■■ NOT HERE.
        ;mov edx, l                   ;◄■■■ NOT HERE.
        loop myloop

        mov edx, OFFSET msg1          ;◄■■■ RIGHT HERE!
        call writestring

        mov eax, l                    ;◄■■■ RIGHT HERE! MUST BE EAX.
        call writedec

        exit 

        main ENDP
        end main
```